# How to handle NAs in correlation output in spite of "pairwise.complete.obs"

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate correlation of a variable (g) with the remaining variables in a scale. It shows up NA for a specific group of variables. (s1, s2, s3...)

The values in the variables look like this:

```
g  = c(1, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA)  
s1 = c(NA, 3, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, 4, 4, NA)
s2 = c(NA, 3, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, 1, 4, NA)
s3 = c(NA, 2, NA, 2, NA, 4, NA, 2, 5, NA)
```

It shows correlation to other variables in the scale. 
Example of those variables:

```
as1 = c(4, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA)
ag1 = c(1, NA, 4, NA, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA)
```

I've used the following code: data set "dn"

```
x <- dn["g"]
y <- dn[1:20] # all variables

cor(y,x, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

output:

```
var_name           g
ag1                0.66254379
ag2               -0.76100601
ag3                0.76110091
s1                 NA
s2                 NA
s3                 NA
s4                 NA
s5                 NA
as1                0.65019200
as2                0.45664999
as3               -0.33246108
```

I also tried "everything", "all.obs", "na.or.complete" and "complete.obs" instead of "pairwise.complete.obs"

I have not been able to figure out why these NAs are appearing. I've been checking for other possible errors in my code, with no luck so far. While I continue to try, is there any other way I can make r calculate the correlation in spite of the NAs?

Note: All values are numeric

Comment: Between `g` and `s1`, there are no complete pairs. For every non-`NA` value in `g`, there's `NA` in corresponding observation in `s1`. If you replace some of `NA`s in `s1` by integers, it'll work fine. So problem is with your data, not with your code.

Comment: To add to the comment from @Narendra  - the `cor` help page "Details" section addresses this.  It says you can get "NA entries if there are no complete pairs for that pair of variables" when using `pairwise.complete.obs`.